# My pyspark application is taking longer than sum of times taken by all my stages (shown in spark ui)

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata

I recently got started with pyspark. I have been working on a project where we receive lots of data (something of 300 million records). Earlier, we had tried to solve this with pandas which took lot of time and memory to run on such big files. So, we decide to move from pandas to pyspark expecting it to be better.
To test the pyspark application, I have run the code on a very small file (which has 0.1 million records). While the pandas code just took 4 minutes to run, pyspark application is taking 17-41 minutes (I have run the code multiple times to get this range).

Specs of the pc which I have used:

- OS: windows
- Ram: 8 GB
- CPU cores: 4
- Pyspark version: 3.3.2
- Python version: 3.9.12

To dig into this a bit deeper, I have explored spark UI. I added the time taken by each job (as shown in UI) and it turned out to be 11 seconds only. I was just wondering if the jobs has only consumed 11s, why is my pyspark application taking much much much longer (17-41 mins).

Data Mechanics's delight:

[image]

Comment: There is no way this can be answered without knowing your code, how you partition your data, what your data looks like, etc.

Comment: My data is in excel format. The code involves basic transformations like join, groupby and multiplications.